# PowerShell to get database schemas

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell

I am able to connect to a remote SQL Server with the instance name using PowerShell. I am using an XML file (something like a configuration file) which includes all my database details. PowerShell uses this for connection establishment.

Now I want to get all "schemas" associated with a particular database that is already defined in that XML file. How can I achieve that using Powershell scripting?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to pull this data from the flat XML file, or the database?

Comment: @ThomasStringer: No..I have my databasename in an XML file. But I need to pull the schemas corresponding to that database from SQL Server. 

Note: I am trying this remotely.

Comment: Can you provide the format of your XML file you are using?

Comment: What's the scope of this question? Do you need help with XML in any way, or is that just background? When you say "I want to get all "schemas"", do you just need a list of the schema names from a database? Or, do you want to access objects within each schema in the database? If so, what do you want to do with the database schema objects?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid instance of the SMO `Server` object defined as $ServerObject. The following code will allow you pull the names of all schemas in the database `UserDatabase01`:

```
$Database = $ServerObject.Databases | ? { $_.Name -eq "UserDatabase01" }
$Database.Schemas | Select Name
```

For more information on schema properties available through SMO, see the documentation for the [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.schema_members(v=sql.90).aspx) class. Unfortunately, the version of SMO for SQL 2005 is missing a lot of properties for this class. Newer versions are backwards compatible, you may want to look into installing a newer version:

- [SQL 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)
- [SQL 2014 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to extract your databases as [.dacpac files](http://web.archive.org/web/20140208053045/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2014/01/18/dacpac-braindump.aspx), which can be used in Visual Studio to translate to a full database schema.

```
#extract all your database schemas as dacpacs
$server = 'PICARD'

$dbs = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database tempdb -Query 'SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id >4'

foreach($db in $dbs.name){
$cmd = "& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe' /action:Extract /targetfile:'C:\dacpacs\$db.dacpac' /SourceServerName:$server /SourceDatabaseName:$db"

Invoke-Expression $cmd
}
```

We use this in my environment to extract our schemas on a daily basis.  Head over to my blog for the [full post on this technique](http://www.mikefal.net/2015/02/03/dynamically-extracting-dacpacs-with-powershell/).